# Unable to install Browser Sync on Windows 10

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, browser-sync

I'm trying to install browser-sync on my Windows 10 using the command:**

`npm install -g browser-sync`

And this is the error I'm getting (image attached below)

Can anyone help me solve this error?

Following are the versions I'm using:
node js v8.12.0
npm version 6.4.1

Comment: Hi Spriha, welcome to Stackoverflow. Can you paste the logs on console in the question?

Comment: Install the latest version of nodejs and try it out